# Differential Geometry: How to find curvature and torsion, given only the Binormal

Tags: differential-geometry

I have to find the curvature and torsion of a curve (parametrised by arc length), given only the Binormal vector.

Whilst I understand how to find these if I have the curve, I cannot for the life of me work out how to go in this direction.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You cannot. Fix any (constant) binormal vector $v$, this defines a plane $\Pi$. Take *any* curve on such plane, this will have binormal $v$. The curve will have zero torsion, but arbitrary curvature.

Answer (score 3):

Assume that your curve is differentiable enough. If you know the binormal unit vector $B(s)$, then the Frenet-Serret formulas tell you that $B'(s) = -\tau(s) N(s)$ and so you can recover the absolute value of the torsion as $|\tau(s)| = ||B'(s)||$.

If the torsion is zero, then all you can deduce is that the curve lies on a plane whose normal is $B(s)$ (which is constant). If the torsion is everywhere non-zero, you can reconstruct you the normal vector (up to a sign) as $N(s) = \frac{B'(s)}{||B'(s)||}$. Using Frenet-Serret again, we have

$$ k(s) = ||N'(s) - \left<N'(s), B(s) \right> B(s)||. $$

Comment: (Long story short, you cannot recover the curve in general.)

Comment: Thank you so much. That's perfect..

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I would be more positive and say that "for a generic curve" this allows you to reconstruct the curve up to isometry.

Comment: I don't get the last line, how you conclude that?